# How common is tachycardia as a symptom of COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, cardiology, heart, symptoms, pulse

How common is tachycardia as a symptom of current COVID-19 infection? I have found quite a bit of information about tachycardia *after* COVID, such as [this paper](https://www.amjmed.com/article/S0002-9343(21)00472-1/fulltext) and [this Cleveland Clinic article](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/articles/heart-problems-after-covid), but none about it during infection.

Comment: Keep in mind that fever, hypoxia and dehydration from any cause can cause tachycardia, and COVID often comes with all three, so it could be difficult to distinguish between tachycardia due to indirect causes like these and direct causes by the COVID virus. For that reason there may not be much data on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

*Fever* is a common symptom of COVID-19. Fever is commonly associated with tachycardia, as they are both part of the sympathetic response to illness.

For example:

[Karjalainen, J., & Viitasalo, M. (1986). Fever and cardiac rhythm. Archives of internal medicine, 146(6), 1169-1171.](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/article-abstract/606966)

> we recorded 24-hour electrocardiograms in 27 young men during an uncomplicated acute febrile infection (12 patients had adenovirus, four had influenza, three had Mycoplasma pneumoniae, and eight were undefined) and after recovery. During the first 24-hour recording period, the mean axillary temperature in the whole group was 38.4 °C. The mean heart rate during the febrile period was 84.0 beats per minute. After recovery, it was 66.5 beats per minute. When the temperature rose by 1 °C, the heart rate increased on the average by 8.5 beats per minute. During the febrile period, the heart rate remained high, even during sleep.

Therefore, it would be surprising if tachycardia were not as common with COVID as fever is, and in the presence of fever an elevated heart rate would not be that unusual.

However, something as simple as measuring "how common is fever with COVID-19" is not actually simple, especially because of the denominator. If you collect people with COVID-19 infections, you're going to be biased towards collecting people that are sickest. Those who don't have any symptoms likely don't know they are infected at all; those with milder symptoms are unlikely to present at a medical facility.

From a couple meta analyses:

[Islam, M. A., Kundu, S., Alam, S. S., Hossan, T., Kamal, M. A., & Hassan, R. (2021). Prevalence and characteristics of fever in adult and paediatric patients with coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19): A systematic review and meta-analysis of 17515 patients. PloS one, 16(4), e0249788.](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0249788) 79% of COVID-19 cases in adults being associated with fever

[Grant, M. C., Geoghegan, L., Arbyn, M., Mohammed, Z., McGuinness, L., Clarke, E. L., & Wade, R. G. (2020). The prevalence of symptoms in 24,410 adults infected by the novel coronavirus (SARS-CoV-2; COVID-19): A systematic review and meta-analysis of 148 studies from 9 countries. PloS one, 15(6), e0234765.](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0234765) gives 78%.

Rather impressive agreement (I didn't look carefully, they may certainly have overlapping source studies) but keep in mind the potential bias in cases observed. I think it's sufficient to say that for people with moderate to severe cases of COVID-19, fever is very common, and it would be very unusual if it was not associated with elevated heart rates because that sort of fever typically is.

Answer (score -3):

As a direct symptom, it's not predictive. Like all immune mediated reactions, changes in chronotropy occur, meaning you'd very likely see elevated pulse in people with symptomatic SARS-CoV-2 infections due to the usual trifecta of elevated body core temperature and sweating, cytokine activity shunting fluids, thus dehydration and lowered blood pressure. In infections impacting ventilation, a mild respiratory acidosis can often be seen. Elevated arterial PCO2 has a vasodilatory effect, meaning you'll also see a compensatory component here.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences. Answers here expected to [include references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/) to back up claims and information in them. Please [edit] your answer to include your sources. Here is a list of [reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources) to get you started in case you need them.